# Scraping sports odds in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I need an R script to scrape sport betting odds from the webpage

https://www.betxpert.com/matchcenter/fodbold

Clicking on a specific match directs to the overview of odds offered by different bookmakers. The script needs to run through all matches and collect the odds.

I have already tried the `rvest`-package using CSS selectors found from the SelectorGadget-app (https://selectorgadget.com/). For example

`library('rvest')`

`url <- 'https://www.betxpert.com/matchcenter/fodbold/oestrig-letland/24147621`

`webpage <- read_html(url)`

`webpage %>% 
  html_nodes(".has-caret")`

where ".has-caret" is the suggested CSS selector for the elements I need (decimal odds). Running the above code returns

`{xml_nodeset (0)}`

which neither makes sense to me nor is the desired output. Any suggestions, also with the use of other packages and/or approaches, are welcome.

Comment: Sure, you're using the most basic form of webscraping. You might try to up that some. You can use `webpage <- html_session(url) %>% read_html()` for starters. This will enable the scraper to handle cookies, referal url, and other things. Then you can add a user_agent (search stack overflow for rvest user agent) to convince the site that you are using Chrome and not R to view their site. If that all didn't work then you could look at setting up RSelenium.

Comment: You also could use the network monitor in your browser to see where the data is coming from since it is being loaded dynamically by a script. The downside to dynamic content loaded after the fact is that it is harder to use base level packages. The upside is that you can watch the network monitor to see where the script is getting its data and access their API directly. The main table: https://www.betxpert.com/main/widget/odds_table?event_id=24147621&market_type_id=1&template=table&href=operator&display_prev_odds_caret=1&view_type=view_type_mc&period_id=1&players_header=